# Regeluar expression to allow one space between two words

Tags: regex

I have to check expression in java script to allow only follow formats in my textbox:

```
first three positions letters/numbers 
one space
another four positions only numbers
```

asd 1234

or

123 1233

I have got   `/^([a-zA-Z0-9]\d{3})\s+(\d{4})$/`

Which is not working please help/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not only allowing multiple spaces, but your initial expression is a character class *followed* by a digit repeated three times. You just needed to get rid of the extra \d.

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s(\d{4})$/
```

Answer (score 1):

To allow only one space you need to use

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s(\d{4})$/
```

Instead of:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]\d{3})\s+(\d{4})$/
```

`\s+` matches 1 or more spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s(\d{4})$/
```

There was `[a-zA-Z0-9]\d{3}` before the space which means *character or number then three numbers*

Answer (score 0):

`[\w]{3}[\s]{1}[\d]{4}` Check out more at rubular.com